# Understanding code of Mixed effects model using Stata

Tags: stata, mixed-models

From a researcher using Stata I got data and the following code:

```
. xtmelogit choicea network2 treatment2 treatment3 trustor2 if (trustor>0) & 
      (period>0) || subgrid: || subjectidtr: , var
```

- Is it correct that `||` does not indicate some OR operator, but indicates a random effect? How is the "`:`" related?
- Does the IF statement here simply mean that only the cases will be selected that have a score of higher than 0 on `trustor` and `period` above 0?
- What is `var` exactly?

I have to implement it in R, but for now I am not sure if what I understand from it, is actually correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First bullet: yes. The variable before the colon is the variable identifying the groups, the variables (possibly none) after the colon are the random effects.

Second bullet: yes

Third bullet: short for `variance`, shows the random effects in terms of variances and covariances instead of standard deviations and correlations.

You can read the helpfile here: http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?xtmelogit

Comment: First bullet: so does that mean when nothing is after the colon that it is just the intercept? Thanks for your answer!